# cannot read property key of undefined in FRIDA

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, frida

I am hooking an app now i m founding this error i have already tried many solutions one of which is following:

```
Java.perform(function() {
 
var main;
    Java.choose('ca.c.edu.char.g', {
                onMatch: function(instance) {
                    main = instance;
                },
                onComplete: function() {console.log(main.Key);}
            });

});
```

Here Key is a method i found after decompiling it with jadx-gui but it is not working ..Any help??

in the function Java.choose **char** is package and its class is **g**

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "not working". Do you gen an error, is your code triggered at all or what is the actual problem?

Comment: I mean that after decompiling i found that there is method named as key now i got this type of error **ReferenceError: 'g' is not defined**  here **g** is class name

Comment: If the name of the method `Key` or `key`? Java is case sensitive, hence there is a difference between both methods. Also make sure there is only one method of this name (method overloading same name but different parameter types) otherwise use `overload` definition of Frida as shown here: https://codeshare.frida.re/@dzonerzy/stringcompare/

Comment: What are you trying to log? Why not use Java.use() and overload the function or init?